# How to loop through JSON with the help of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, json

I am working on Google Charts, I want to make a column chart. I have JSON data with me but the JSON is not matching the JSON I have required for the Google Chart.

- In my database there is only a single row so am I am not able to loop it through
- I just want to format my JSON into new one

The JSON I am getting:

```
  [
  [
    "Payment mode",
    "Amount"
  ],
  [
    "Cash",
    1355774,
    "Swiggy",
    38560,
    "KB",
    0,
    "BigBasket",
    0,
    "Zomato",
    0,
    "OMC",
    0,
    "CBOnline",
    0,
    "DineOut",
    0,
    "sodexoCpnCard",
    0,
    "PhonePe",
    0,
    "Mobiwiki",
    0,
    "CreditCard",
    0,
    "Coupn",
    0,
    "Paytm",
    0,
    "CreditAmt",
    0
  ]
]
```

The JSON I want:

```
[
                    "Payment mode",
                    "Amount"
                  ],
                  [
                    "Cash",
                    1355774,

                  ],
                  [
                    "Swiggy",
                    38560,

                  ],
                  [
                    "KB",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "BigBasket",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "Zomato",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "OMC",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "CBOnline",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "DineOut",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "sodexoCpnCard",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "PhonePe",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "Mobiwiki",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "CreditCard",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "Coupn",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "Paytm",
                    0,

                  ],
                  [
                    "CreditAmt",
                    0
                  ]
                ]
```

How can I loop this JSON?

Here is my server end Java code:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            LinkedList<Object> list1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
            list1.add("Outlet");
            list1.add("Amount");
            mainList.add(list1);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
            list = new LinkedList<Object>();
            cashAmt =resultSet.getLong("CashAmt");
            swiggyAmt=resultSet.getLong("SwiggyAmt");
            kbAmt=resultSet.getLong("KBAmt");
            BigBasketAmt=resultSet.getLong("BigBasketAmt");
            zomatoAmt=resultSet.getLong("ZomatoAmt");
            omc=resultSet.getLong("OMC");
            cbOnline=resultSet.getLong("CBOnline");
            dineOut=resultSet.getLong("DineOut");
            sodexoCpnCrd=resultSet.getLong("SodexoCpnCrd");
            phonePe=resultSet.getLong("PhonePe");
            mobikwiki=resultSet.getLong("Mobikwiki");
            creditcardAmt=resultSet.getLong("CreditCardAmt");
            couponAmt=resultSet.getLong("CouponAmt");
            paytmAmt=resultSet.getLong("PayTMAmt");
            creditAmt=resultSet.getLong("CreditAmt");

            list.add("Cash");
            list.add(cashAmt);
            list.add("Swiggy");
            list.add(swiggyAmt);
            list.add("KB");
            list.add(kbAmt);
            list.add("BigBasket");
            list.add(BigBasketAmt);
            list.add("Zomato");
            list.add(zomatoAmt);
            list.add("OMC");
            list.add(omc);
            list.add("CBOnline");
            list.add(cbOnline);
            list.add("DineOut");
            list.add(dineOut);
            list.add("sodexoCpnCard");
            list.add(sodexoCpnCrd);
            list.add("PhonePe");
            list.add(phonePe);
            list.add("Mobiwiki");
            list.add(mobikwiki);
            list.add("CreditCard");
            list.add(creditcardAmt);
            list.add("Coupn");
            list.add(couponAmt);
            list.add("Paytm");
            list.add(paytmAmt);
            list.add("CreditAmt");
            list.add(creditAmt);
            mainList.add(list);
            str = gson.toJson(mainList);

        }
        // System.out.println(list);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Hi @vivek shingh, I thought the database only has a single row, why is outlet and amount in another subarray? :)

Comment: @StephanT. that i am passing statically in a list

Comment: Why not to format the response at the server?

Comment: Why you're not looping and extracting? You can write a `even`-> Name and `odd` -> amount. logic by yourself.

Comment: @Teemu don't know how to do it with java. :(

Comment: @Kaushik  can you help me with a snippet please ?

Comment: @viveksingh what is the logic here. looks like you want to group 2 values in an array.

Comment: @varatharajan yupp.

Comment: @viveksingh Maybe you should ask that instead of this question ..? But please, post a new question for that, it is completely different from this JS question.

Comment: @Teemu  I have added my java code also please see if you can help

Comment: @viveksingh First of all, you are not using JSON, the way it is supposed to. You should have the array of JSON instead of array all the way. Still, we are having answer for this too.

Comment: @viveksingh I hava a very simple custom solution according your needs, I hope you are expecting to construct array of array items. I think you want the output array like this. `[['Payment mode', 'Amount'],
['Cash', 1355774],
['Swiggy', 38560],
['KB', 0],
['BigBasket', 0],
['Zomato', 0],
['OMC', 0],
['CBOnline', 0],
['DineOut', 0],
['sodexoCpnCard', 0],
['PhonePe', 0],
['Mobiwiki', 0],
['CreditCard', 0],
['Coupn', 0],
['Paytm', 0],
['CreditAmt', 0]]`

Comment: you should create a proper object in the `java` server side code. There is no computation required in the UI side. Create a list of Object and then make that as response.

Comment: @Kaushik i am doing that only see my java code also ,if you can help

Comment: @varatharajan   yup

Comment: @viveksingh answer is already posted by Stephan T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really just want the json to be formatted like your request, you can

**A:** alter your server side function to build the json right from the beginning

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
        list.add("Outlet");
        list.add("Amount");
        mainList.add(list);
while (resultSet.next()) {
        String[] keys= {"CashAmt","SwiggyAmt","KBAmt", "BigBasketAmt","ZomatoAmt","OMC","CBOnline","DineOut", "SodexoCpnCrd", "PhonePe", "Mobikwiki", "CreditCardAmt", "CouponAmt", "PayTMAmt", "CreditAmt"}; 

        for (String s: keys) { // iterate over all keys
           list = new LinkedList<Object>();
           list.add(s);
           list.add(resultSet.getLong(s));
           mainList.add(list);
        }
        String str = gson.toJson(mainList);

    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    System.out.println(str);
```

**B:** use the code to build your new json:

```js
var data = [
  [
    "Payment mode",
    "Amount"
  ],
  [
    "Cash",
    1355774,
    "Swiggy",
    38560,
    "KB",
    0,
    "BigBasket",
    0,
    "Zomato",
    0,
    "OMC",
    0,
    "CBOnline",
    0,
    "DineOut",
    0,
    "sodexoCpnCard",
    0,
    "PhonePe",
    0,
    "Mobiwiki",
    0,
    "CreditCard",
    0,
    "Coupn",
    0,
    "Paytm",
    0,
    "CreditAmt",
    0
  ]
];
var count = 0;
var result = [];
result[count++] = data[0];
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
  result[count++] = [data[1][i], data[1][++i]];
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this the answer i was looking for, but i have also uploaded my `java` server code if you can help me out there for a little bit that how can i loop through java ,it would be very helpfull

Comment: you should edit the question then and show us how resultSet is defined, that would help :) thanks mate

Comment: I edited my answer, please let me know if you are satisfied. The only thing different is that the keys won't be named like you wanted: not cash but cashamt for example

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to create an array of array from the array you specified, you can use [_.chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk) from lodash as below.

```
data = 
  [
    "Cash",
    1355774,
    "Swiggy",
    38560,
    "KB",
    0,
    "BigBasket",
    0,
    "Zomato",
    0,
    "OMC",
    0,
    "CBOnline",
    0,
    "DineOut",
    0,
    "sodexoCpnCard",
    0,
    "PhonePe",
    0,
    "Mobiwiki",
    0,
    "CreditCard",
    0,
    "Coupn",
    0,
    "Paytm",
    0,
    "CreditAmt",
    0
  ]


data = _.chunk(data, 2);
```

and respone is something like this

```
[
    [
        "Cash",
        1355774
    ],
    [
        "Swiggy",
        38560
    ],
    [
        "KB",
        0
    ],
    [
        "BigBasket",
        0
    ],
    [
        "Zomato",
        0
    ],
    [
        "OMC",
        0
    ],
    [
        "CBOnline",
        0
    ],
    [
        "DineOut",
        0
    ],
    [
        "sodexoCpnCard",
        0
    ],
    [
        "PhonePe",
        0
    ],
    [
        "Mobiwiki",
        0
    ],
    [
        "CreditCard",
        0
    ],
    [
        "Coupn",
        0
    ],
    [
        "Paytm",
        0
    ],
    [
        "CreditAmt",
        0
    ]
]
```

all you need to do now is add the static list at the first index

For cash and other details, I coundn't find any relation between `outlet` and `sales` that you want in response since you request array doesn't have `sales`

Comment: thats not working,and also i have a one more list which is `outlet` and `amount`

Comment: that array is header which is required for making the chart  `outlet is payment mode`  and amount `sales is amount`

Comment: but you have mapped outlet to sales which is not present in your request object as I mentioned above. Also I could not get a relation between them as you mentioned if it an static data so can't you map it manually?

Comment: first list is static,but not the second list, i want to loop second loop

Comment: data in my answer is your second list, I have skipped your first sub array since it was static as you mentioned. _.chunk returns an array of array for the specified size argument

Comment: but i want all that data into a single list only

Comment: reponse is a single list (array of array), as you mentioned in your post. I've added the response example of `_.chunk`, but you need to add the static list at index 1. Also you need an outer array to accumulate data in something, so used an outer array

Answer (score 0):

just a for loop with step 2...

```js
    let JSON_In = [
      [ "Payment mode", "Amount" ],
      [ "Cash",   1355774,
        "Swiggy",   38560,
        "KB",     0,
        "BigBasket", 0,
        "Zomato",  0,
        "OMC",  0,
        "CBOnline",  0,
        "DineOut",  0,
        "sodexoCpnCard",  0,
        "PhonePe",  0,
        "Mobiwiki",  0,
        "CreditCard",  0,
        "Coupn",   0,
        "Paytm",  0,
        "CreditAmt", 0    ] ];

    let JSON_Out = [];

    JSON_Out.push( JSON_In[0] );

    for (let i=0, iMax= JSON_In[1].length; i<iMax; i+=2 ) {
      JSON_Out.push(  [JSON_In[1][i], JSON_In[1][i+1] ] );
    }

    console.log( JSON_Out );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest one with array,reduce

```js
let tr=[
  [
    "Payment mode",
    "Amount"
  ],
  [
    "Cash",
    1355774,
    "Swiggy",
    38560,
    "KB",
    0,
    "BigBasket",
    0,
    "Zomato",
    0,
    "OMC",
    0,
    "CBOnline",
    0,
    "DineOut",
    0,
    "sodexoCpnCard",
    0,
    "PhonePe",
    0,
    "Mobiwiki",
    0,
    "CreditCard",
    0,
    "Coupn",
    0,
    "Paytm",
    0,
    "CreditAmt",
    0
  ]
]


let temp=[];
let r=[];
 r=tr[1].reduce((o,a)=>{
 
temp.push(a);
 if(typeof a=='number')
 { 
   o.push(temp);
   temp=[];
 }
 return o;
},[])


  r.unshift([
    "Payment mode",
    "Amount"
  ]);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this using plain javascript by using simple for loop:

```
  var jsonData = [
  [
    "Payment mode",
    "Amount"
  ],
  [
    "Cash",
    1355774,
    "Swiggy",
    38560,
    "KB",
    0,
    "BigBasket",
    0,
    "Zomato",
    0,
    "OMC",
    0,
    "CBOnline",
    0,
    "DineOut",
    0,
    "sodexoCpnCard",
    0,
    "PhonePe",
    0,
    "Mobiwiki",
    0,
    "CreditCard",
    0,
    "Coupn",
    0,
    "Paytm",
    0,
    "CreditAmt",
    0
  ]
]
```

All you need to do is just to use a simple for loop and adding it in new array:

```
var newArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<jsonData[1].length; i++) {
    var changedArr = [jsonData[1][i], jsonData[1][++i]]
    newArr.push(changedArr)
}
console.log(newArr)
```

To join this new array with `payment mode` array, you can simply just call `newArr.concat([jsonData[0]])` this line of code.